# Assigning view model to data context: when does view model override XAML element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm learning WPF and MVVM. I'm curious about what happens in a particular situation.

Assuming that my view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the situation is where my code has already constructed my view model and then assigns it to my window's `DataContext`.

At the point in time that I assign the view model to `DataContext`, the value in my view model may be different than the value in the XAML element. And so I'm curious about which value *wins*.

I assumed the XAML element would pull in all the values from my view model but that is not what seems to be happening. Changes made to my view model correctly notify and update the XAML elements. But those changes made before I set `DataContext` are *not* reflected in the XAML elements.

Can anyone confirm my interpretation is correct? I've Googled extensively but could not find anything on this specific issue. Yet that seems to be the behavior in my application. Would appreciate someone else perspective or a link to a more detailed discussion.

I'm curious about the situation where my view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, my code builds my view model and then assign it to my windows `DataContext`.

The problem is, at that stage where I assign to `DataContext`, the value in the XAML element may not match my view model. So which one wins.

Based on my testing, it appears that the value already in the XAML element wins. And if I want it set to the value in my view model, I must set it somehow or have my view model send a new property-changed notification.

Comment: Can you post an example, showing your bindings?

Comment: How can your XAML controls' properties hold any value when you have set a binding? There is no such thing as `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}" Text="My default value" />`

Comment: @HeySatan: There is a lot of code. It would require some thought on how I could rewrite it to demonstrate in a form that would fit here.

Comment: @Jai: I don't set the property value in XAML. But it appears to be set to `null`. And when I attach my data context, it appears to still be set to `null` even though my view model has data.

Comment: As soon as the DataContext is set, the Bindings should be re-evaluated. Could you show a simple example where this would not happen?

Comment: Okay, it is going to be extremely difficult for someone else to find out what is happening (or what problem you are exactly experiencing) if you don't provide any kind of codes. For example, setting datacontext can be done via at least three ways, and each way has subtle differences. All we need is an example of a control from XAML with its binding, how you set the datacontext, as well as how you wrote the source properties.

Comment: "it appears that the value already in the XAML element wins. And if I want" ... want what?  Are you okay?  Did you faint before finishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your changing your data template to show a hardcoded value rather than the default value provided by the binding.

For example in a TextBlock you can only assign the Text property once, either via a binding syntax where the value is sourced from the DataContext, or a static value.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display}"/> <- only uses the DataContext
<TextBlock Text="123"/> <- only shows the static value
```

If you try and set the Text property twice, you get an error:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display}">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    123
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

You can provide the binding with a fallback value when there is no valid value available via the DataContext such as an exception being thrown, but the DataContext value wins when it provides a value:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display, FallbackValue=123}" />
```

If you want to set a default value, you might be best to set a default in the constructor of the DataContext class and leave the binding in the Xaml to only source from the DataContext

Comment: Thanks but that doesn'the seem to be it. I have no default value in the markup. As stated, I can update my data and it is correctly reflected in the control. And there are no errors. It is simply not picking up the current values at the time I assign the data context.

Comment: Do the getters on the properties in question get read at the time the data context is applied?

Comment: Sorry, I've been having trouble figuring out exactly what WPF does. I try setting breakpoints but then I seem to get a flurry of hits. More than I expect.